# Outputting to a user-decided text file using method

Tags: java, file-io, io, text-files

To keep it short, I am trying to create a method which takes in as an argument a
output file stream name, and then allows the user to write to that text, and append to it with a while loop. Here's what I wrote:

```
public void insertRowsToFile(OutputStream output) throws IOException {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //here is my mistake that i dont know how to solve (outputstream, boolean is undefined)
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                          new OutputStreamWriter(
                              new FileOutputStream(output, true))); 
    boolean answer = true;
    while (answer == true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the row:");
        String entered = keyboard.nextLine();
        out.println(entered);
        System.out.println("Would you like to write more? (yes to continue)");
        String answer2 = keyboard.next();
        if (!answer2.equals("yes"))
            answer = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `output` variable should be `File` instead of `OutputStream`.

Remember, that the constructor of `FileOutputStream` is legal only as the following ones:

- `new FileOutputStream(File, boolean)`
- `new FileOutputStream(String, boolean)`

Here is the correct method declaration:

```
public void insertRowsToFile(File output) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

---

**Edit, Untested:** Or the better way would be keeping `OutputStream` as the parameter but change the initialization of the `out` variable:

```
public void insertRowsToFile(OutputStream output) throws IOException { 
    ...
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output)); 
    ...
}
```

---

**Edit 2:** A difference between `OutputStream` and `File` classes:

- `OutputStream`: Is an abstract class that accepts output bytes and sends them to some sink.
- `File`: Is an class is an abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

Source from: [TutorialsPoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/)

Comment: Right, I tried the edit part, but I'm not sure if it will work, as one needs to use true to append from my understanding. I was told without the use of true, the contents of the file would be deleted before writing something inside. However, I do like the first solution you have posted, though it leads me to ask myself another question, what is the difference between OutputStream and File?